# How to count recurring identical values in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Pandas Series with True/False values, and I need to count how often a value occus that is identical with the previous value.

Whenever the value changes, the  counting should restart at 1.

```
pd.Series([True, False, False, False, True, True, False])

0     True        --> 1
1    False        --> 1
2    False        --> 2
3    False        --> 3
4     True        --> 1
5     True        --> 2
6    False        --> 1
dtype: bool
```

I tried various combinations of shift() and cumsum(), but without success.

Any hints?

Ale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups by consecutive values with compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and use it for [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, False, False, True, True, False])

s1 = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
print (s1)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    1
dtype: int64
```

Detail:

```
print (s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
dtype: int32
```

Another solution is count `True`s and `False`s separately and then sum outputs:

```
cm1 = s.cumsum()
s1 = cm1-cm1.where(~s).ffill().fillna(0)
cm2 = (~s).cumsum()
s2 = cm2-cm2.where(s).ffill().fillna(0)
s3 = s1.add(s2).astype(int)
print (s3)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    1
dtype: int32
```

Detail:

```
print (s1)
0    1.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    0.0
dtype: float64

print (s2)
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    1.0
dtype: float64
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(2018)
N = 1000000
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], N))
#print (s)

def jez1(s):
    return s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)

def jez2(s):
    cm1 = s.cumsum()
    s1 = cm1-cm1.where(~s).ffill().fillna(0)
    cm2 = (~s).cumsum()
    s2 = cm2-cm2.where(s).ffill().fillna(0)
    return s1.add(s2).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (jez1(s))
print (jez2(s))

In [173]: %timeit jez1(s)
1 loop, best of 3: 199 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit jez2(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 92 ms per loop
```

Comment: I had exactly same, every word :)